# How to add an extra text to user's input upon form submission

Tags: javascript

With my salesforce's web-to-lead form, I would like to add an extra text to whatever value users input on the "description" input.

ex) user inputs "I want to inquire about xx product" + ["extra text from me"]

I was trying to come up with something with JavaScript but I kept messing it up. Could you please recommend me a way of doing it clean?

you can look at the actual page at https://cleardent.com/demo

here's my HTML

```
<div class="row"> 
  <!-- Homework for Jason Begin -->
  <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-3"> 
    <!-- Homework for Jason End -->
    <form id="sfDemoForm" action="https://webto.salesforce.com/servlet/servlet.WebToLead?encoding=UTF-8" method="POST" class="sky-form">
      <input name="captcha_settings" value="{&quot;keyname&quot;:&quot;IC_ClearDent_Main_Demo&quot;,&quot;fallback&quot;:&quot;true&quot;,&quot;orgId&quot;:&quot;00D1I0000002QyG&quot;,&quot;ts&quot;:&quot;&quot;}" type="hidden">
      <input name="oid" value="00D1I0000002QyG" type="hidden">
      <input name="retURL" id="retURL" value="https://test.cleardent.com/demo-thankyou-bc.html" type="hidden">

      <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debug" value=1>                              --> 
      <!--  <input type="hidden" name="debugEmail" value="ppli@cleardent.com">      -->

      <fieldset>
        <!--<label class="label" for="first_name">First Name</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
          <input  id="sffirst_name" maxlength="40" name="first_name" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="First name">
        </label>
        <!--<label class="label" for="last_name">Last Name</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-user"></i>
          <input  id="sflast_name" maxlength="80" name="last_name" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="Last name">
        </label>
        <!--<label class="label" for="email">Email</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-15"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-envelope"></i>
          <input id="sfemail" maxlength="80" name="email" size="20" type="email" required placeholder="Email address">
        </label>
        <!-- <label class="label" for="phone">Phone</label>-->
        <label class="input margin-bottom-25"><i class="icon-prepend fa fa-phone"></i>
          <input id="sfphone" maxlength="40" name="phone" size="20" type="text" required placeholder="Phone">
        </label>
        <!--<label class="label" for="description">Notes</label>-->
        <label class="textarea textarea-resizable margin-bottom-25">
          <textarea id="sfdescription" name="description" placeholder="Is there something specific you want to see from ClearDent?"></textarea>
        </label>
        <input id="sfstate" name="state" type="hidden">
        <input id="sflead_source" name="lead_source" type="hidden" value="Website">
        <input id="sfcompany" name="company" type="hidden">
        <input id="sfCampaign_ID" name="Campaign_ID" type="hidden" value="7011I000000d5auQAA">
      </fieldset>
      <div id="recaptcha" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LeXmEAUAAAAAG7VJd6Z8YCVkP44AgAlqCUmpRAi" data-callback="submitDemoToLead" data-size="invisible"> </div>
      <footer>
        <button id="sfdemoPreSubmit" class="btn-u"><i class="fa fa-paper-plane fa-fw"></i> Get Your Free Demo</button>
        <!--<button class="btn-u btn-brd" onclick="window.history.back();"><i class="fa fa-arrow-left fa-fw"></i> Back</button>--> 
      </footer>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

and here's my current attempt. I am trying to add "ClearConnect" but it seems to take away user's input.

```
    $("#sfdemoPreSubmit").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#sfcompany").val($("#sflast_name").val() + ", " + $("#sffirst_name").val());
    $("#sfphone").val(cleanPhNum($("#sfphone").val()));
    $("#sfstate").val(getProvince($("#sfphone").val()));
    $("#sfdescription").val(+ "ClearConnect");
    $("#sfDemoForm").validate();
    if ($("#sfDemoForm").valid()) {
       grecaptcha.execute();
    }
  });
```

Comment: Can you trim the code samples down to specifically which part is giving you an issue?

Comment: just did! could you have a look?

Comment: So, when you're trying to update #sfdescription in this way, I don't believe that the `(+ "ClearConnect")` is doing what you're expecting it to do (its not clear to the code what you're trying to add with the text).  Another way to write this would be `$("#sfdescription").val( $("#sfdescription").val() + "ClearConnect");` This is assigning the value of #sfdescription plus the text.

Answer (score 0):

In your code, it looks like you're asking jQuery to add "ClearConnect" to the value of #sfdescription.

```
$("#sfdescription").val(+ "ClearConnect");
```

The `.val()` method will update the value with whatever it is presented with, but it does not natively recognize its own value at this point.  One way to assign the value back to #sfdescription is to pull the current value and add your desired text afterwards.

```
$("#sfdescription").val( $("#sfdescription").val() + "ClearConnect");
```

```js
function addClearConnect(){
  $("#sfdescription").val( $("#sfdescription").val() + "ClearConnect");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type="text" id="sfdescription" value="Test123" />
<button onclick="addClearConnect()">Add Clear Connect</button>
```